# InstallShield: FilterProperty column of ISComponentExtended table?

Tags: installshield

Anybody has an idea what this custom table is used for and what is the meaning of this column in particular? Documentation is silent about it and the info on the Net is scarce.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same with my InstallShield project. Have you been successful figuring out how to generate the values in FilterProperty column in ISComponentExtended table?

Many thanks!

Charles

---

### Updates:

The FilterProperty is just a string of GUID with all "-" replaced with "`_`", beginning with a "_" and ending with "_FILTER". I wrote a simple tool to import my files into the project and the project compiles fine.

Comment: Yes, I saw what's inside, but couldn't find connection to anything else in the schema. IIRC, these were separate GUIDs, not foreign keys to something else...